# On my hosting plan I cannot have access the Internal Server errors

Tags: apache-2.2, shared-hosting

I am using a share hosting with IWeb. And they hide all the Internal Server errors. But I need them to know what is causing my Apache Script to crash.

Is there any way to catch a HTTP 500 Internal Server error... So I can know what is causing it?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

Here is .htaccess:

```
 AuthUserFile .htpasswd
 AuthType basic
 AuthName "Secret Files"
 Require valid-user
```

When I load the page I get the popup for the username and password... Then when I type in everything... and click OK I get Internal Server Error... To me it does not make sense. Why is it sending the error only after the user tried to login.

Answer (score 2):

You could spend a lot of time crufting up something that may or may not catch the errors (you haven't given enough information to know if that might be possible in your case), or you could  just give your money to a service that actually provides you with the resources you need, instead of continuing to pay someone who isn't.